# Shutdown Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, guice, servlets

I have Quartz scheduler in my web application with Guice. I followed code found [here](http://www.codesmell.org/blog/2009/01/quartz-fits/). Everything works fine, but I can't figure out how to shutdown scheduler. My context listener looks like this:

```
public class MyAppContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener{

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new QuartzModule(), new MyAppServletModule());
    }
}
```

And Quartz module looks like this:

```
public class QuartzModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(SchedulerFactory.class).to(StdSchedulerFactory.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    bind(GuiceJobFactory.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    bind(Quartz.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
}
```

What is the best way to shutdown scheduler when application is being stopped or undeployed?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

The app server will call the `contextDestroyed()` when your wep-app is stopped.

This will give you time to call the necessaries on your `QuartzModule` ***(inside the contextDestroyed() method)*** just before the web-app stops.

Just remember to add the `<listener>` tags in the **web.xml** of your web-app.

Comment: I thought about using contextDestroyed, but how can I get access to injector in contextDestroyed() method?

Comment: If you look at the QuartzModule class, it is defined as a SINGLETON, so there will only be one Quartz instance in the VM. So no matter where you get the instance from, it will be the same Quartz instance. The following in the contextDestroyed() should work: i.getInstance(Quartz.class).shutdown();

Comment: I am having the same problem, but this answer is not helping me. Since ServletContexListener is not created by guice how would I get injector there?

Comment: You can try adding a shutdown hook on a thread that starts the scheduler. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html

Comment: just to point out what helped me: see how to access an Injector in [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001369/40331)